# How to use CSS Loader in my website?

Tags: html, css

I want to use this css loader before full load site.

CSS loader source: http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit.

On this site no documents or help.

How to use this HTML code in my website?

HTML:

```
<div class="sk-cube-grid">
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
  <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sk-cube-grid {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    background-color: #333;
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-delay: 0.2s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-delay: 0.4s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-delay: 0.2s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 0.3s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-delay: 0s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    animation-delay: 0.1s; }
.sk-cube-grid .sk-cube9 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-delay: 0.2s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
    0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    } 35% {
          -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
          transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
      }
}

@keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
    0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
    } 35% {
          -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
          transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
      }
}
```

After refresh page, not work this code...

Comment: It gives you the source if you click Source at the top.  Just copy and paste it.

Comment: You're going to need JavaScript logic that listens to some sort of event in order to display or hide a `div` that contains the loader.

Comment: Additionally, if you click on the View in GitHub link, it takes you to https://github.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit, which has usage instructions. Please, try and do some research before asking on Stack Overflow, as indicated in [ask].

Comment: @PAckerman, Thank you so much, Do you know the jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the css inline in the head of the document. Then you can either add your css under it or in the footer before the closing body tag (isn't proper HTML but it works fine).

Add a css class for a preloader div and have it position fixed, top, right, bottom, left all as 0 and a high z-index. Place the HTML for the preloader in that div.

Then add your ja files after the css if they r in the footer otherwise add them before the closing body tag anyway.

And then you want some jquery or JavaScript to display none the containing div from above.

HTML:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  HEAD STUFF
  <style>
    .sk-cube-grid {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 100px auto;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube {
      width: 33%;
      height: 33%;
      background-color: #333;
      float: left;
      -webkit-animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
      animation: sk-cubeGridScaleDelay 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube1 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube2 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
      animation-delay: 0.3s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube3 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
      animation-delay: 0.4s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube4 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
      animation-delay: 0.1s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube5 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube6 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
      animation-delay: 0.3s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube7 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube8 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
      animation-delay: 0.1s;
    }
    .sk-cube-grid .sk-cube9 {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
      animation-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
      0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
      }
      35% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
        transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
      }
    }
    @keyframes sk-cubeGridScaleDelay {
      0%, 70%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
        transform: scale3D(1, 1, 1);
      }
      35% {
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
        transform: scale3D(0, 0, 1);
      }
    }
    div#preloader {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 999;
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="preloader">
    <div class="sk-cube-grid">
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube1"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube2"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube3"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube4"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube5"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube6"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube7"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube8"></div>
      <div class="sk-cube sk-cube9"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
   
  
  HAVE YOUR MAIN BODY HERE
  
  
  CSS FILE LINKS & JS FILE LINKS GO HERE (YOU NEED JQUERY)
   <script>
    $("#preloader" ).fadeOut(300);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See my update. Don't expect people to do everything for you, I'm just in a good mood. @Shayvard

Comment: New update has a full working example with minimal effort needed by you. You are MOST welcome. :) Remember to accept this answer and upvote it :D

Comment: @shayvard sorry but I'm not doing everything for you now. use google. There are plenty of resources available.

Comment: Thank you, Why give me negative?

Comment: Who said it was me? But probably because you put 0 effort into figuring it out yourself.